# An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

Hi I'm working with Flutter 2.2.2 and I'm having some issues when i try to run the command pod install
`An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

[Xcodeproj] Consistency issue: build setting `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` has multiple values: `{"Release"=>"14.0", "Debug"=>"8.0", "Profile"=>"8.0"}``

**I have modified my podfile but the error is the same**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Branch'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']='14.0'
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end
  end
end
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

**Can someone know how to solve it? I have tried many possible solutions but the results are the same, I tried running flutter clean -> pod update -> pod install. I don't know if this helps but I'm also using pod version: 1.11.3**

I have run many commands hoping that the app is going to execute but I only have this error.